# Use multi-core in LINUX to run R-script

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing

I have a function called "my_function" and I want to run in parallel using mcapply in in LINUX using multi-cores. I have 10 cty_id's 20 years to run for each cty_id. How can I use mcapply to make this fast run using 4 cores? I have tested my function to run one county and one year at a time and it is working fine. But, I want to speed up the process rather than manually changing the years and cty_id one at a time.

```
cty_id <- c(205,15,37,59,25,133,11,23,21,19)
val_yr <- c(1998:2017)

my_function <- function(cty_id,val_yr) {

<do something here> ()

}
```

I have my code as follows but it does not do the job and crashes.

```
library("parallel")
mcapply(c(205,15,37,59,25,133,11,23,21,19),FUN=my_function, val_yr=years[1998:2017], 4L)
```

Can somebody help me to run this faster?

Please let me know what global variables I need to define.

Revised R. code file below

```
in_file11 <- 'PLSS_KS_All_1999_2017.txt' 
in_file12 <- 'PLSS_KS_All_WeeklySM_1998_2017_BILINEAR.txt' 
in_file13 <- 'PRISM_WeeklyPrcp_Sum_800m_1998_2017_BILINEAR.txt'

in_data11 <- fread(in_file11,drop = 1)
in_data12 <- fread(in_file12,drop = 1)
in_data13 <- fread(in_file13,drop = 1)

in_datan <- as.data.table(full_join(in_data12, in_data13))
in_data1 <- as.data.table(full_join(in_data11, in_datan))

in_file2 <- 'KS_pp_Wheat_hist_YieldID_1998_2017.csv' 
in_file3 <- 'All_counties_1999_2017.csv'

in_data2 <- fread(in_file2)
in_data3 <- fread(in_file3)

years <- c(1998:2017)
st_id <- c(15)  
crop_id <- c(11)

my_function <- function(cty_id,val_yr) {

<do something here> ()

}


registerDoFuture()
plan(multiprocess)
num.cores <- detectCores()-1
cluztrr <- makeCluster(num.cores)
registerDoParallel(cl = cluztrr)

plan(cluster, workers = cluztrr)


county_id <- c(19,205)
val_year <- c(1998:1999)

foo <- expand.grid(county_id,val_year)


foreach(i = 1:nrow(foo), globals = c("in_data1","in_data2","in_data3"), .export = c("years","st_id","crop_id")) %dopar% {
  my_function(foo[i,]$Var1,foo[i,]$Var2)
}

stopCluster(cluztrr)

Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'in_data1' not found"
In addition: Warning message:
In e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) :
  already exporting variable(s): st_id, crop_id
```

Comment: user3408139 [globals problem](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future#globals) You have to identify objects that are being exported  and define them as instructed, eg: `globals = c("a", "slow_sum"))` In source code you can see that this problem comes from too big object size [source code](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/blob/master/R/globals.R#L228)

Comment: OK. Can you please tell me what should I do then.? I am relatively new to R programming.

Comment: there should be large objects in your R session. Before running code restart session. Then try to identify what object might cause this. Do you have big matrices or data.frames? try to `globals = c("largeMATRIX", "largeDF"))`

Comment: I am reading large text files and data frames. Please see my whole R script above. This is what I am running in LINUX.  When you say "largeMATRIX" do I have to define all data frames as globals after reading from text files. Please help me know how I can make this script run. Thanks again.

Comment: You don't need that many packages. Only `data.table` for `fread` and something that calls `lr_past`. When does error occur? After which line?

Comment: Error happens after reading .txt and .csv files (See my code above for the location shows error happens here). I ran the script in linux > Rscript my_script.R. Please educate me what global variables I need to define here. Thanks again.

Comment: Also,please let me know what global variable and where I need to define in the script. thanks.

Comment: Still making reference to missing files and not even presenting an error message or specific description of "crashes".

Comment: I have posted the revised code and the error above. It shows the error of "in_data1" not found. please see the code and error above.

Answer (score 2):

It's future now :-)

Use `future` package for parallel computing in `R`. `doFuture` is it's subpackage for loops (`foreach` loops).

```
library(doFuture)
registerDoFuture()
plan(multiprocess)

cty_id <- c(205,15,37,59,25,133,11,23,21,19)
val_yr <- c(1998:2017)
my_function <- function(X,Y) {
    cat(X, Y, "\n")
}

result <- foreach(i = cty_id) %dopar% {
    foreach(j = val_yr) %do% {
        my_function(i, j)
    }
}
```

**Edit**

This is how I would write such code for myself (shrink multiple loops into one)

```
A <- c(205, 15, 37, 59, 25, 133, 11, 23, 21, 19)
B <- c(1998:2017)
foo <- expand.grid(A, B)
myFunction <- function(X, Y) {
    cat(X, Y, "\n")
}
foreach(i = 1:nrow(foo)) %dopar% {
    my_function(foo[i, ]$Var1, foo[i, ]$Var2)
}
```

More about future on [it's GitHub page](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future) and really good introduction on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q19_bOBTwYI).

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the code and ran but I get this error (Please see above)